# Series expansion of $(1-cx)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion, power-series

I am trying to understand the series expansion of $$(1-cx)^{1/x}$$ The wolframalpha seems to solve the problem by using taylor series for $ x\rightarrow 0$ and Puiseux series for $ x\rightarrow \infty$. Any ideas how can I calculate them ?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-cx%29%5E%281%2Fx%29+series

Here is the link of the problem

Comment: It's not exactly and I will probably close that question. See I have deleted. No more duplicated. This version seemed much simpler to ask and gain answer

Comment: Near $x=0$ I write $f(x)=\exp{\frac{1}{x}\log(1-cx)}$, expand the log by the usual series and see that $f(x)$ is a product of exponentials $\exp(-c)\exp(-c^2 x/2)\exp(-c^3 x^2/3)\dots$ which lets one identify the first few coefficients. But I can't see what happens at $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said in comments
$$y=(1-c x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\quad \implies \quad \log(y)=\frac{1}{x}\log(1-cx)$$ For small values of $cx$
$$\log(y)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {c^n} n\,x^{n-1}$$ Now, using $y=e^{\log(y)}$
$$\color{blue}{y=1 +c\,e^{-c}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{ c^{n}}{\alpha_n}\,P_n(c)\,x^n}$$ The $\alpha_n$ form the sequence $A053657$ in $OEIS$ (have a look [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+24%2C+48%2C+5760%2C+11520&language=english&go=Search)) and the first $P_n(c)$ are listed below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(c) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 c-8 \\
 3 & (c-6) (c-2) \\
 4 & 15 c^3-240 c^2+1040 c-1152 \\
 5 & (c-4) \left(3 c^3-68 c^2+408 c-480\right) \\
 6 & 63 c^5-2520 c^4+35280 c^3-211456 c^2+526176 c-414720 \\
 7 & (c-6) \left(9 c^5-450 c^4+7800 c^3-55792 c^2+151104 c-120960\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$

Looking separately at $P_{2n}(c)$ and  $P_{2n+1}(c)$, it *seems* that there are some interesting patterns (worth to be explored ?).

For large values of $x$, using $L=\log(-cx)$
$$\color{blue}{y=1+  c \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n!\,c^n} Q_n(c,L) \frac 1 {x^n}}$$ where the first $Q_n(c,L)$ are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & Q_n(c,L) \\
 1 & L \\
 2 & c L^2-2 \\
 3 & c^2 L^3-6 c L-3 \\
 4 & c^3 L^4-12 c^2 L^2-12 c L+12 c-8 \\
 5 & c^4 L^5-20 c^3 L^3-30 c^2 L^2+60 c^2 L-40 c L+60 c-30 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Again, possible interesing patterns.

Comment: Maybe there is but not hope for the $\rightarrow \infty$ case?

Comment: @seVenVo1d How do you define your expression for $x>1/c$? Wolfram's idea is clearly $$
(1 - cx)^{1/x}  = \exp \left( {\frac{{\log (1 - cx)}}{x}} \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\log ^k (1 - cx)}}{{k! x^k }}}  = 1 + \frac{{\log (1 - cx)}}{x} +  \ldots \\ \approx 1 + \frac{{\log (1 - cx)}}{x} \approx 1 + \frac{{\log ( - cx)}}{x},
$$ but you need to define $\log$ for negative real values.

Comment: @seVenVo1d. Answer edited

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful

Comment: @seVenVo1d. Thé fun was mine ! Cheers. 